# I'm new to ASP NET MVC 5, I'm trying to get a data from a table and display it on a textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. I'm trying to get the ITEMNAME from tbl_inventorycontrol.

```
@model RSMI.Models.Database.tbl_STOCKCARD


@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ITEMCODE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ITEMCODE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ITEMCODE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-24 col-md-12">
            <input type="button" value="Search Item"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SearchItemCode","Stockcard")'" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
```

It should it should get the ITEMCODE value from tbl_stockcard. Then in stockcard controller, when I click search button, it should get the itemname in tbl_inventorycoller equal to the tbl_stockcard.ITEMCODE.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where is your code snippet related to view? In addition, include your `tbl_inventorycontrol` class as well.

Comment: You appear to get `itemname` before redirecting and discarding the retrieved value!

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do with the filter result. Seems you mismatched you `return` statements. You want returning View with your item if found. Please consider this approach

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Searchitem(tbl_inventorycontrol tbl_Inventorycontrol )
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {   
        var item = db.tbl_inventorycontrol.Where(tbl_STOCKCARD => tbl_STOCKCARD.ITEMCODE == tbl_Inventorycontrol.SUPPLIES).FirstOrDefault();
        
        if (item != null)
        {
            return View(item);
        }    
    }
    return View(tbl_Inventorycontrol);
}
```